# after_save error in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model

I have two models linked to each other and I am trying to do an after_save,  create in the model and code is as follows.

```
class CustomerBill < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :updating_and_creating_ledger_items
  has_many :customer_ledgers, :dependent => :destroy

  def updating_and_creating_ledger_items
    CustomerLedger.create(:date => self.date, :customer_id => self.customer_id, :user_id => self.user_id)
  end
end
```

customer ledger model

```
class CustomerLedger < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer_bill,  :foreign_key => "customer_bill_id"
end
```

Now the problem is the program executes perfectly but the value are not been put in the database. If I check Customer ledger it is still empty.

The values are not getting stored. what seems to be the problem? Guidance towards this matter will be helpful.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: try changing create for create! and let me know what happens

Comment: when i did create! the form did not get saved and it went to edit and i got the error wen i submitted as Couldn't find **CustomerBill with id=30**

Comment: now i added :customer_bill_id => self.id and the form is not getting saved..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CustomerLedger` may be failing a validation check.  Replace:

```
def updating_and_creating_ledger_items
  CustomerLedger.create(:date => self.date, :customer_id => self.customer_id, :user_id => self.user_id)
end
```

with:

```
def updating_and_creating_ledger_items
  ledger = customer_ledgers.build(:date => self.date, :customer_id => self.customer_id, :user_id => self.user_id)
  ledger.save(:validate => false)
end
```

Comment: Thank you Mike... i was missing the validate false option...hence i was getting the prob...now it is working fine. :)

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
  validates_associated :customer_ledgers
```

In customer_bill.rb

Try

```
ledger = customer_ledgers.build(:date => self.date, :customer_id => self.customer_id, :user_id => self.user_id)
ledger.save
```

EDITED for to avoid Validations, use

```
ledger = customer_ledgers.build(:date => self.date, :customer_id => self.customer_id, :user_id => self.user_id)
ledger.save(:validate => false)
```

Comment: well i tried this. the code is getting executed correctly but still the ledger table is empty.. :( :( not getting what seems to be the problem.

Comment: Just Curious, Why you are storing `date, customer_id, user_id` in `CustomerLedger` When you are already saving it in `CustomerBill` and you have Association between this two?

Comment: actually it was a complex code where i was calculating and storing bill total and due amount and stuff... but to identify the problem i stripped down the code...and left it with just one line of create option. and association made is ledger belongs to bill and bill has many ledgers. and now i have added the validates associated.

Comment: So, do you have any validation in CustomerLedger? may b that validation not get passed and so it is not get saved. Try ledger.save(:validate => false)

Comment: @Salil- a million thanks....the validation was causing the problem... just update in ur answer so that other people will come to know... :)

Comment: Instead of `.build` and then `save` just write `create`: the same effect but shorter :)

Comment: @nathanvda- yeah in question i was doing create only...the problem was occuring due to validation... :) i made validation false. now it is working. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting the `customer_bill_id` in the `create`, change `create` to `build` as so:

```
customer_ledger.build(:date => self.date, :customer_id => self.customer_id, :user_id => self.user_id)
```

Comment: i got the following error **undefined method `build' for #<Class:0x38c7d98>**